# How to download a file generated "on the fly" with Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I want to download and rename a PDF file that is generated "on the fly" by an Angular app.

With this code, the PDF file is downloaded but I want to rename it before writing to disk.

```
  //Download PDF
  await secondTab.waitForSelector('img[title="Format PDF"]', { visible: true, timeout : 10000 })
  await secondTab.waitForTimeout(10000);
  var current_element = await secondTab.$('img[title="Format PDF"]');
  var parent_node = await current_element.getProperty('parentNode');
  await parent_node.click();
  console.log("Downloading PDF");
```

I wasn't able to find a solution. All solutions talk about files downloaded from URL.

I tried to trace events on the page (cf. PageEventObjet), but no one catch this "on the fly" generated PDF file.

My question : is there a way to catch that stream, name it and save it to disk ?

Thank you very much.

Note : I dont want to play with the File system (i.e. find my downloaded PDF, rename it, move it, etc.)

Comment: im not sure about pdf but iv used puppeteer to load up a url and take a screenshot of the page and saved it as a png file. Im sure you can use imagemagick to conver to pdf though - is that what your trying to do ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont want to convert my PDF in a image. I want to save the real PDF file.